# default browser's drag and move functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that I would like to be able to move by dragging on the page. As I understand it should work by default in every browser, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.
Here is my page:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:1000px; height:900px;border:solid;z-index:30;float:left">
    <div id="image-helper" style="position:absolute;width:1000px; height:900px;z-index:20;float:left" >
        <img id="image" src="images/test.jpg" style="width:500px;height:400px;cursor:pointer;z-index:10;" alt=""/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Do I miss something in css?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't move an image just by doing this. You have to listen for mouse events to update the position of the image in javascript.

More specifically, you'll have to catch

- [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)
- [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)
- [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/)

Here's a very raw demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/CvVte/

**CSS :**

```
img {
 position: fixed;   
}​
```

**Javascript :**

```
var mouseIsDown = false;
$('img').mousedown(function(e){
    mouseIsDown = true;
    pos = $(this).offset();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if (!mouseIsDown) return;
    $('img').css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
 }).mouseup(function(){
     mouseIsDown = false;
 });​
```

I'll let you finalize in order to be more precise and use start drag position (hint : use [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset)). And you could also remove the mousemove event handler when the mouse button is up.

Answer (score 0):

To do drag and drop you need javascript, and in jquery, you can use the ui drag'n'drop : http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/